# Panic Error on Boot - Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, error-handling

I recently did an update on my machine and ever since Ubuntu will not boot properly. I get an error message and I have to go into recovery mode in order to start the boot process. I have tried recovery but it's still happening. Is there anything I can enter in the command line to fix this or should I just reinstall Ubuntu? 
[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a corrupted drive (Was there a power failure?)

Comment: Well..we did have a power outage in the last month but I didn't notice a problem until after I did a major update that asked for my user password. It must have changed something major because things havent been right since.

Comment: Ok that's probably not it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I think I got it!

Start the computer taking not of what grub says the version of the linux kernel you have (i.e. `3.0.0-19-generic`) then run the command `mount -o remount,rw /` Finally, run `update-initramfs -u -k 3.0.0-19-generic`

**IMPORTANT: REPLACE `3.0.0-19-generic` WITH THE VERSION *GRUB2* SAYS YOU HAVE!!!**

Comment: Ok...when I did that I got: ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic': Op eration not permitted cp: cannot create regular file '/boot/initrd.img -3.13.0-55-generic.dpkg-bak': Permission denied

Comment: Is there a way to permanently go back to 3.13.0-54-generic?

Comment: @user3533000 try the new instructions

Comment: I received the same error. Seems like I will have to save my files and reload...thanks for the help.

Comment: really? Try running `mount --all` after `mount -o remount,rw`

Comment: Today I was prompted to run another full system update and the problem has seemed to correct itself on it's own so problem solved. Thanks for all your help!